# White border-right is not appearing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the bootstrap toggle plugin specifically the "Custom Text" example of this plugin. In the documentation this example "Custom text" appears with a white border right, but that border is not appearing. Do you know why?

Working example:https://jsfiddle.net/w2oy1t1o/1/

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item 0</th>
      <th scope="col">Item 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Item 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which of the elements in the source is supposed to get the white border? Can you create a [mcve], so that we don't have to guess at which of the css files we're supposed to look in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the bootstrap stylesheet to get the styling. 
Add this line in the `head`:
`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/w2oy1t1o/7/

Comment: Thanks, but in the question fiddle it also uses bootstrap.min.css but a more recent version. Do you know if there isn't a plugin for that newest version?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. bootstrap-toggle doesn't yet work with bootstrap 4. You can refer to these issues opened on github for workarounds/discussions: https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/186 , https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/80